# $x'=(2x-t+1)^2$, where $x=x(t)$ satisfies $x(3)=x_0$, defined in interval $(t_-,t_+)$ which $x_0$ has $t_+=\infty$ and $t_-=-\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I have the following question :

$$x'=(2x-t+1)^2$$ Where $x=x(t)$ satisfies $x(3)=x_0$, defined in  interval $(t_-,t_+)$.

Which $x_0$ has $t_+=\infty$ and $t_-=-\infty$ find limits of $x(t)$ as $t \rightarrow \infty$ and $t \rightarrow -\infty$?

**What I did:**

I thought to go to the singular solutions since I know $t_+=\infty$ and $t_-=-\infty$ and the limit of $x(t)$ as $t \rightarrow \infty$ and $t \rightarrow -\infty$ are the singular solutions since the solutions are constant.

The equation has the form of $x'=f(ax+bt+c)$ so I defined $y(t)=2x-t+1$ and we know that $y'(t)=2x'-1=2y^2-1$ which is autonomus equation.

the singular solutions are $y=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$

This is where I got stuck the question is for $x_0$ how can I express $y$ in terms of $x_0$, also how can I know if these are the only possibilities for $x_0$?

Any help will be appreciated, Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Substituting $$v(t)=2x(t)-t$$ then $$v'(t)=2x'(t)-1$$ and we get
$$\frac{1}{2}\left(v'(t)+1\right)=(v(t)+1)^2$$
so
$$\frac{\frac{dv(t)}{dt}}{2v(t)^2+4v(t)+1}=1$$
now integrating
$$\int\frac{\frac{dv(t)}{dt}}{2v(t)^2+4v(t)+1}dt=\int 1dt$$

Comment: I did something similar I reach to $\int_{v_0}^{v} 2((v(t))^2-1=\int_{3}^{t} 1dt$ since $v'(t)=2x'(t)-1=2v(t)^2-1$ I took $v(t)=2x(t)-t+1$ the $\int_{3}^{t} 1dt$ comes from the relation of separable ode where $f(t)=1$ I solve the integral and got $t-3=\frac{2y^3}{3}-y-\frac{2y_0^3}{3}+y_0$ now i'm not sure to proceed